# Replace default client side validation by custom one in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, client-side-validation

I have a view model containing a `DateTime` property, for which I want to provide a text box using using a custom format (only month and year, "MM.YYYY"):

```
public class MyModel {
  public DateTime? DateField {get; set;}
}
```

Formatting the value for the TextBox is easy (using the format string). I also have implemented a custom model binder to do the conversion and this works fine.

I still have a problem with client side validation: I can implement a custom validator deriving from `ValidationAttribute` which implements `IClientValidatable` and set up the corresponding jquery.validate adapters etc.

But MVC still adds the "default" validation attribute `data-val-date` (in addition to my custom validation attribute `data-val-monthyeardate`) to the input field, so the default check still applies and the input "MM.YYYY" is rejected.

Is there any way to suppress the default client side validation for a data type and replace it with a custom one (instead of "adding" the custom one)?

Comment: How is your `monthyeardate` looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the framework doesn't let you override the real type with some custom attribute or even override the `ModelMetadataProvider` for specific types, you'll have to register your own global `ModelMetadataProvider` that fools the validator to think it's actually a `string`.

Something like:

```
public class MyModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        if (attributes.OfType<ExcludeCharAttribute>().Any())
            modelType = typeof (String);

        return base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName); ;
    }
}
```

Register it using:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyModelMetadataProvider();
```

Still, since the core problem is a client-side problem, I would deal with it purely with client-side code. In your `monthyeardate` adapter you can force removal of the `date` validation (I can provide an example if you'll share your `monthyeardate` code).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataproviders(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! In the meanwhile I came up with your second solution too: when adding the adapter (using `jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add`), I put something like `options.rules['date'] = false;` in the registration code. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is hacky but one simple thing you could do is add:

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.methods.date = function () { return true; }; 
});
```

So that the default data-val-date always returns true along with firing your custom date validation.

Comment: This will disable date validation on all date inputs in the page.

Comment: That is true, I think it is probably not the best solution available.  I would be interested to see a better solution.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a little older, and just in case someone doesn't think about it (and since I cannot leave comments yet), to enhance @AlexC response, you can add validation to to that statement.

For instance, I use moment.js for date validation ([moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)), and this allows you to add your own validation rules.

```
if (moment(a, "M/YYYY").isValid() || moment(a).isValid())
{
    return true;
}
```

This will check to see if it is a regular date, and also in this case, if the date is in "M/YYYY" format. If one of these are true, it accepts the validation.